# new page sidebar-template by default

Tags: templates, theme-twenty-eleven, customization

Using twenty-eleven theme, need to change default template for new page from standard to sidebar.

anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I would hook into the `new_page` action, and then use [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to update the post meta value for `_wp_page_template`:

```
<?php
function wpse31124_set_page_default_template( $page_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'sidebar-page.php' )
}
add_action( 'new_page', 'wpse31124_set_page_default_template' );
?>
```

You could hook into other actions, but they might stomp on your ability to use the default template. Using `new_page` will ensure that the callback only changes the page template meta data value when a new page is *created* initially.

Answer (score 0):

If it wont mess you up you could switch the template file names. Although every time the theme is updated you would probably have to do this over and over again.